# How to set an Ionic (>=2) toolbar to a different background color than the navbar

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have an Ionic application where I would like to have a toolbar within the nav bar, where the toolbar has a different background color to the "top title" section of the navbar.

I have the following markup...

```
    <ion-header>

      <ion-navbar>      
        <ion-title>Main header</ion-title>       
      </ion-navbar>  

      <ion-toolbar style='background-color:green'> 
        <ion-title >Subheader</ion-title>    
      </ion-toolbar>

    </ion-header>
```

and also an example plunk [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/zushb5?p=preview)

Of course I'd like to do this in the sccs, (rather than inline style), but just trying to find how to override the default.

I would like the toolbar to be a different color as in the image below...

[image]

I set the navbar color using

```
.toolbar-background{
    background-color: color($colors, secondary-lite);
  }
```

which seems to set anything within the navbar.

Anyone know how I can just set this "secondary" toolbar?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Ionic way* to do that would be to include all the colors in the `$colors` map, and then use the `color` attribute of the `ion-toolbar` component:

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar color="custom-blue">      
    <ion-title>Main header</ion-title>       
  </ion-navbar>  

  <ion-toolbar color="custom-green"> 
    <ion-title>Subheader</ion-title>    
  </ion-toolbar>

</ion-header>
```

And in your `variable.scss` file:

```
$colors: (
  primary:    #01579b,
  secondary:  #32db64,
  danger:     #f53d3d,
  light:      #f4f4f4,
  dark:       #222,

  //...

  custom-blue:   #0277bd,
  custom-green:  #008c00
);
```

Comment: Great, thanks, this allows me to do exactly that I need for the colors.

Comment: It's working for the ion-navbar but not for the ion-toolbar on my config

Answer (score 0):

exist a class in css and you need to overwrite or change style of class.

```
.toolbar-background-md {
    border-color: #b2b2b2;
    background: #f8f8f8;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this still colors the navbar as well.